# CPU and memory communication

Tags: c, memory, pointers, cpu

I'm programmer-beginner, but I want to understand the things a bit more deeply. I did some research and read quite a lot of text, but I'm still yet to understand some things..

When coding a basic thing (in C):

```
int myNumber;
myNumber = 3;
printf("Here's my number: %d", myNumber);
```

I found out that (mainly on 32-bit CPU) integer takes place of 32 bits = 4 bytes. So at first line of my code CPU goes into the memory. The memory is byte-addressable, so CPU chooses 4 continuous bytes for my variable and stores the address to first (or last) byte.

On the second line of my code CPU uses his stored address of the MyNumber variable, goes to that address in the memory and finds there 32 bits of reserved space. His task now is to store there the number "3", so he fills those four bytes with the sequence 00000000-00000000-00000000-00000011.
On the third line it does the same - CPU goes to that address in memory and loads the number stored in that address.

*(First question - Do I understand it right?)*

What I don't understand is this:
The size of that address (pointer to that variable) is 4bytes in 32-bit CPU. *(Thats why 32-bit CPU can use max 4GB of memory - because there are only 2^32 different addresses of binary length 32)*
Now, **where the CPU stores these addresses?** Does he have some sort of its own memory or cache to store that? And **why it stores the 32 bit long address to 32 bit long integer?** Wouldn't it be better to simply store in its cache that actual number than the pointer to that when the sizes are the same?

And last one - if it stores somewhere in its own cache the addresses to all those integers and the lenghts are the same (4 bytes), it will need exactly the same space for storing the addresses as for the actual variables. But variables can take up to 4GBs of space so CPU must have 4GB of its own space to store the addresses to those variables. And that sounds strange..

Thank you for help!
I'm trying to understand that but it's so tough.. :-[

Comment: Those are pretty interesting questions. I'd like to see what the answer is too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (First question - Do I understand it right?)

The first thing to recognise is that the value might not be stored in main memory at all.  The compiler might decide to store it in a register instead, as this is more optimal.<sup>1</sup>

> The memory is byte-addressable, so CPU chooses 4 continuous bytes for my variable and stores the address to first (or last) byte.

Assuming that the compiler does decide to store it in main memory, then yes, on a 32-bit machine, an `int` is typically 4 bytes, so 4 bytes will be allocated for storage.

> The size of that address (pointer to that variable) is 4bytes in 32-bit CPU. (Thats why 32-bit CPU can use max 4GB of memory - because there are only 2^32 different addresses of binary length 32)

Note that the width of an `int` and the width of a pointer don't have to be the same, so there's not *necessarily* a connection with the size of the address space.

> Now, where the CPU stores these addresses?

In the case of local variables, the address is effectively hardcoded into the executable itself, typically as an offset from the stack pointer.

In the case of dynamically-allocated objects (i.e. stuff that's been `malloc`-ed), the programmer typically maintains a corresponding pointer variable (otherwise there would be a memory leak!).  That pointer might also be dynamically-allocated (in the case of a complex data structure), but if you go back far enough, you'll eventually reach something that's a local variable.  In which case, the above rule applies.

> But variables can take up to 4GBs of space so CPU must have 4GB of its own space to store the addresses to those variables.

If your program consists of independently `malloc`-ing millions of `int`s, then yes, you'd end up with just as much storage required for the pointers.  But most programs don't look like that.  You typically allocate much bigger objects (like an array, or a big struct).

> cache

The specifics of *where* stuff is stored is architecture-specific.  On a modern x86, there's typically 2 or 3 layers of cache sitting between the CPU and main memory.  But the cache is not independently addressable; the CPU cannot decide to store the `int` in cache *instead of* main memory.  Rather, the cache is effectively a redundant copy of a subset of main memory.

Another thing to consider is that the compiler will typically deal with *virtual addresses* when allocating storage for objects.  On a modern x86, these are mapped to *physical addresses* (i.e. addresses that correspond to physical storage bytes in main memory) by dedicated hardware, along with OS support.

---

<sub>1. Alternatively, the compiler may be able to optimise it away entirely.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure - when I add into my code `printf("%p", &myVariable);`, the result I see is for example **0022FF4A** - just the hexadecimal 32-bit number. So that's not the actual physical address but just some virtual one? (I was fancy to try some experiments with memory management, as C language looks to be very compliant with that.. :) )

Comment: @Jeyekomon: As soon as you starting *observing* the address of an object, the compiler has no choice but to give it one.  But if you don't observe it, then the compiler is free to store it in registers only.

Comment: @Jeyekomon: And yes, that's a virtual address (assuming you're working on a platform that has a virtual address system).

Answer (score 3):

> On the second line of my code CPU uses his stored address of the MyNumber variable, goes to that address in the memory and finds there 32 bits of reserved space.

Nearly correct. Memory is basically unstructured. The CPU can't see that there are 32 bits of "reserved space". But the CPU was instructed to read 32 bits of data, so it reads 32 bits of data starting from the specified address. Then it just has to hope/assume that those 32 bits actually contain something meaningful.

> Now, where the CPU stores these addresses? Does he have some sort of its own memory or cache to store that? And why it stores the 32 bit long address to 32 bit long integer? Wouldn't it be better to simply store in its cache that actual number than the pointer to that when the sizes are the same?

The CPU has a small number of *registers*, which it can use to store data (common CPUs have 8, 16 or 32 registers, so they can only hold the particular variables that you're working with here and now). So to answer the last part first, yes, the compiler certainly might (and probably will) generate code to just store your `int` into a register, instead of storing it in a memory, and telling the CPU to load it from a specified address.
As for the other part of the question: ultimately, every part of the program is stored in memory. Part of it is a stream of instructions, and part of it is in chunks of data scattered around memory.

There are a few tricks that help with locating the data the CPU needs: part of the program's memory contains the *stack*, which typically stores local variables while they're in scope. The CPU always maintains a pointer to the top of the stack in one of its registers, so it can easily locate data on the stack, simply by modifying the stack pointer with a fixed offset. Instructions can directly contain such offsets, so in order to read your int, the compiler could for example generate code which writes the int to the top of the stack when you enter the function, and then when you need to refer to that function, have code which reads the data found at the address the stack pointer points to, plus the small offset needed to locate your variable.

Answer (score 0):

And also keep in mind that the adresses your program sees may not be (or rather rarely are) physical adresses starting from the 'beginning of the memory' or 0. Mostly they are offsets into a specifc memory block where the memory manager knows the real address and the accesses via base+offest as the real data storage.

And we do need the memory since caches are limited ;-)

Mario

Answer (score 0):

Internal to the CPU there is one register that contains the address of the next instruction to be executed. The instructions themselves keep information where the variable is. If the variable is optimized, the instruction may point to a register, but in general, the instruction will have an address of the variable being accessed. Your code, after compiled and loaded in memory, have all that embedded! I recommend looking into assembly language to get a better understanding of all that. Good luck!